# Не парсятся ссылки

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Есть код

```
import lxml
import requests
import json
import csv

url = "https://pilomaterialov.net/catalog/"
r = requests.get(url)
src = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
all_prod = soup.find_all("div", class_="category-name")
for item in all_prod:
  item_title = item.text
  item_link = item.get("href")
  print(f"{item_title}: {item_link}")
```

Ошибки нет, но вместо ссылок None. Подскажите в чем ошибка?

```
                          Фанера            
: None
```

Comment: значит, ничего не находит.

Comment: item_link = item.a.get("href")

Comment: @Сергей Ш. Супер...спасибо, огромное!